# NodeJS Parquet write

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, bigdata

I have a bunch of columns ( around 30). Out of which there are arrays, text fields with multiple line space (Word document) etc. I think CSV will not be an apt format because of multiple new lines. I am thinking of using Parquet format.

The file itself needs to be generated via NodeJS.

1. Is there a preferred library for Parquet?
2. Also, is there any recommendation for a specific file format for big query?

Any pointers would be helpful

Comment: Could you clarify where you are storing the files generated using Node.js ?

Answer (score 5):

Node JS libraries on parquet are not well maintained. You can checkout [my other answer on the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74205773/6563567) topic. It lists most popular one's.

- parquetjs
- parquets
- parquetjs-lite
- node-parquet

I would suggest giving below library a try.

**DuckDB** - [DuckDB](https://www.npmjs.com/package/duckdb) is an in-process embedded library/DB. It has a lot of features built around parquet files.

It can write parquet file on disk, write it directly to S3 bucket, etc..

Parquet feature supported by DuckDB - https://duckdb.org/docs/data/parquet
. Here is a simple snippet.

```
var duckdb = require('duckdb');
var db = new duckdb.Database(':memory:');
db.all("COPY (SELECT 'BOB' AS NAME, 'LONDON' AS CITY) TO 'result-snappy.parquet' (FORMAT 'parquet')", function(err, res) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log(res)
});
```

Executing the script:

```
PS C:\Users\user1\Downloads> node .\duck-script.js
[ { Count: 1 } ]
```

[image]

In your case you might have to load the data first to duckdb table and then write it to a parquet file.

**DOCS**

- [Writing table to parquet](https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/import/parquet_export)
- [Writing parquet data directly to S3](https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/import/s3_export)