# Writing .parquet from duckdb prefixes column names with "PARGO_PREFIX_"

Tags: duckdb

DuckDB is changing my column names as I write out to .parquet file, and I can't figure out why.

In a DuckDB memory only instance (on Ubuntu 23.04) I run:

```sql
create table mytable (_id int, str varchar, num int);
insert into mytable (_id, str, num) values (1, 'one', 1);
insert into mytable (_id, str, num) values (2, 'two', 2);
copy (select * from mytable) to 'mytable_splat.parquet' (format 'parquet');
copy (select _id, str, num from mytable) to 'mytable_colnames.parquet' (format 'parquet');
copy (select _id as "id", str, num from mytable) to 'mytable_renamecols.parquet' (format 'parquet');
copy (select * from mytable) to 'mytable.csv' (format csv, header true);
```

I then use `parquet-tools` to show the contents of the .parquet files:

```
$ parquet-tools cat mytable_splat.parquet -f csv
PARGO_PREFIX__id,Str,Num
1,one,1
1,two,2
$ parquet-tools cat mytable_colnames.parquet -f csv
PARGO_PREFIX__id,Str,Num
1,one,1
1,two,2
$ parquet-tools cat mytable_renamecols.parquet -f csv
Id,Str,Num
1,one,1
1,two,2
$ cat mytable.csv
_id,str,num
1,one,1
1,two,2
```

There's two issues here:

- The Parquet output (but not CSV output) capitalizes the first letter of each column that doesn't start with an underscore _
- The Parquet output (but not CSV output) renames columns starting with an underscore, to prefix `PARGO_PREFIX_` on to the column.  `_id` becomes `PARGO_PREFIX__id`.

I'm using DuckDB to write data from Node.js to .parquet files as suggested by this post:  [NodeJS Parquet write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73711197/nodejs-parquet-write)  This seems like a more robust solution than the several `parquetjs` based NPM libraries, but I can't understand or control why these columns are being renamed in .parquet files only.  The root issue is in DuckDB itself, not the NodeJS code.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'd suggest using something other than parquet-tools to read the file, as it's the one prepending the `PARGO_PREFIX_` value: https://github.com/xitongsys/parquet-go/pull/310/files

Comment: Thank you; that's an embarassing mistake on my part, but an easy problem to fix.  Much appreaciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mause answered correctly that DuckDB isn't creating the .parquet file with these incorrect column names, `parquet-tools` was changing the names while printing the contents.

The easiest way for me to validate this was to add a Parquet file inspecter into VS Code, I used [parquet-viewer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dvirtz.parquet-viewer) *(I'm sure there's others that would work as well).

With this extension, I could see that the contents of each of the files that I created in my example above are:

```json
{"_id":1,"str":"one","num":1}
{"_id":1,"str":"two","num":2}
```

@Mause, if you'd like to post your own answer I'd be happy to accept it.  I'm just posting this one to provide some closure to the question.